# Strange issue: Getting different calculation results of the area and perimeter of a polyngn (on different machines and on different times)

Tags: c

I have a program to calculate the area and perimeter of a polygn. Also the program confirms if the result of the area and perimeter calculations are the same of the expected result.

I dont understand what is happening but the verification part, to confirm if the area and perimeter are the same of what it is expected is not working corretly.

For exemple, I test now and I get that "Arrays are the same" in all cases, which is correct because I gave the correct coordinates in the txt file to match each one of the expected results. But I test a little bit later or on a diferente machine, I tested in Linux also, and in some cases it appears "Arrays are diferent". This is really strange to happen without changing the coordinates file or the code.

Do you understand why this strange issue is happening?

This is the text file, with the correct coordinaes to mach the expected results:

```
 1.0 2.5 5.1 5.8 5.9 0.7 
 1.2 4.1 5.1 5.8 6.8 1.9 2.9 0.2
 1.7 4.9 5.1 5.8 7.0 2.8 4.8 0.1 1.5 1.4
 2.1 5.3 5.1 5.8 7.0 3.5 5.9 0.7 2.9 0.2 1.0 2.5
 2.5 5.6 5.1 5.8 6.9 3.9 6.5 1.3 4.2 0.0 1.8 1.0 1.0 3.4
 2.8 5.7 5.1 5.8 6.7 4.2 6.8 1.9 5.2 0.3 2.9 0.2 1.3 1.8 1.2 4.1
```

Program:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {x, y};
typedef struct triangle {
    double v1[2];
    double v2[2];
    double v3[2];
} triangle;
double area(triangle a);
double perimeter(double *vertices, int size);
double side(double *p1, double *p2);


char result[256];
char expected[] = "11.7715.65";     //triangle regular
char expected1[] = "18.1017.02";    //quadrilateral regular
char expected2[] = "21.3317.60";    //pentagon regular
char expected3[] = "23.5518.07";    //hexagon regular
char expected4[] = "24.8018.29";    //heptagon regular
char expected5[] = "25.1418.26";     //octagon regular


int main()
{
    int idx;
    int triangles;
    int index;
    int xycount;
    double xy;
    double triangle_area;
    double polygon_area;
    double perim;
    double polygon_vertices[50] = {0.0};
    triangle a;

    FILE* data;
    char line[256];
    char* token;
    if ((data = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open data file\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof (line), data)){
        xycount = 0;
        polygon_area = 0;

        line[strlen(line) - 1] = 0;
        token = strtok(line, " ");
        while (token != NULL){
            xy = atof(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            polygon_vertices[xycount++] = xy;
        }
        idx = 0;
        triangles = (xycount / 2) - 2;
        for (index = 2, idx = 0;idx < triangles;index += 2, ++idx){
            a.v1[x] = polygon_vertices[0];
            a.v1[y] = polygon_vertices[1];
            a.v2[x] = polygon_vertices[index + 0];
            a.v2[y] = polygon_vertices[index + 1];
            a.v3[x] = polygon_vertices[index + 2];
            a.v3[y] = polygon_vertices[index + 3];

            triangle_area = area(a);
            polygon_area += triangle_area;

        }

        printf("area=%.2f\t", polygon_area);
        perim = perimeter(polygon_vertices, xycount);
        printf("perimeter=%.2f\n", perim);

        sprintf(result, "%.2f%.2f", polygon_area, perim);

        if(strcmp(result,expected) == 0) {
            printf("Arrays are the same\n");
        }
        else if(strcmp(result,expected1) == 0){
            printf("Arrays are the same");        
        }
        else if(strcmp(result,expected2) == 0){
            printf("Arrays are the same");        
        }
        else if(strcmp(result,expected3) == 0){
            printf("Arrays are the same");        
        }

        else if(strcmp(result,expected4) == 0){
            printf("Arrays are the same");        
        }
        else if(strcmp(result,expected5) == 0){
            printf("Arrays are the same");        
        }
        else {
            printf("Arrays are the different");        
        }

    }
    fclose(data);
    return 0;
}

/* calculate triangle area with Heron's formula */
double area(triangle a)
{
    double s1, s2, s3, S, area;

    s1 = side(a.v1, a.v2);
    s2 = side(a.v2, a.v3);
    s3 = side(a.v3, a.v1);
    S = (s1 + s2 + s3) / 2;
    area = sqrt(S*(S - s1)*(S - s2)*(S - s3));

    return area;
}

/* calculate polygon perimeter */
double perimeter(double *vertices, int size)
{
    int idx, jdx;
    double p1[2], p2[2], pfirst[2], plast[2];
    double perimeter;

    perimeter = 0.0;
    /* 1st vertex of the polygon */
    pfirst[x] = vertices[0];
    pfirst[y] = vertices[1];
    /* last vertex of polygon */
    plast[x] = vertices[size-2];
    plast[y] = vertices[size-1];
    /* calculate perimeter minus last side */
    for(idx = 0; idx <= size-3; idx += 2)
    {
        for(jdx = 0; jdx < 4; ++jdx)
        {
            p1[x] = vertices[idx];
            p1[y] = vertices[idx+1];
            p2[x] = vertices[idx+2];
            p2[y] = vertices[idx+3];
        }
        perimeter += side(p1, p2);
    }
    /* add last side */
    perimeter += side(plast, pfirst);

    return perimeter;
}

/* calculate length of side */
double side(double *p1, double *p2)
{
    double s1, s2, s3;

    s1 = (p1[x] - p2[x]);
    s2 = (p1[y] - p2[y]);
    s3 = (s1 * s1) + (s2 * s2);

    return sqrt(s3);
}
```

Comment: Such behaviour is almost certainly because of bugs in the code. There is no need to be so surprised. Just debug it as you would any other bug - reproduce the unexpected behaviour and use standard debugging techniques (ie a debugger) to trace its execution.

Comment: In the `perimeter`in the `for (jdx = 0; jdx < 4; ++jdx)` you don't use `jdx`!

Comment: The line: `else if(strcmp(result,expected2) == 0)` is missing an associated previous`if` clause. Somehow, while doing what should have been a direct copy/paste you managed to miss at least one line of code in the *middle*. As a result this won't compile (there's at least one missing `}`), so it can't possibly produce your problem.

Comment: I update, now I think its ok.

Comment: When a difference is found, I would print the calculated and the expected values both.  This will show you if the issues is a small decimal/rounding issue or a larger, bad memory, or uninitialized memory type issue.

Comment: Try `while (token != NULL){
        xy = atof(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        /* if (token == NULL) break; */
        polygon_vertices[xycount++] = xy;
        printf("%d %e\n", xycount, xy);
    }
`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its not working, with that the code dont runs.

Answer (score 0):

> on a diferente machine, I tested in Linux also, and in some cases it appears "Arrays are diferent".

Consider for example the first [triangle](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=triangle(1,2.5)(5.1,5.8)(5.9,0.7)). Its area is 11.775, and in `expected` you have `11.77` to compare with. Now, rounding errors can lead to results slightly below or above 11.775 on different implementations, and `sprintf(result, "%.2f…` can yield `11.77` or `11.78`, respectively, so the `strcmp` leads to "same" in one case, and to "different" in the other.